# Mouse Down Event not firing (Bubbling events)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I am a novice to WPF. I started learning about RoutedEvents in WPF. I tried a sample and i met up with a problem

```
    <Grid Margin="5" Name="Grid" MouseDown="Window_MouseUp">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5"        Name="FancyLabel" MouseDown="Window_MouseUp" >
        <StackPanel Name="Stack" MouseDown="Window_MouseUp"> 
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Name="txtBlock1">
                Click Any Where
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Margin="50" Name="txtBlock2" >
                Click me also
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Label>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Name="ListMessages"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" Name="cmd_Clear" MouseDown="Cmd_Clear_MouseDown"  >Clear</Button>
</Grid>
```

The handler for the mouseDown event of the button is different from others int the tree hierarchy. The event is not firing..

But if i add in the .cs file the following code

```
 Grid.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window_MouseUp),true);
 Stack.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window_MouseUp), true);
 FancyLabel.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window_MouseUp), true);
 txtBlock1.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window_MouseUp), true);
 txtBlock2.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window_MouseUp), true);
 Img1.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window_MouseUp), true);
 cmd_Clear.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Cmd_Clear_MouseDown), true);
```

the Cmd_Clear_MouseDown event is fired and the event is bubbled up to the grid and the grid fires Window_MouseUp.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1) Is `MouseDown="Window_MouseUp"` everywhere intended?

2) Why not register to `Click` event with `ClickMode="Press"` instead of `MouseDown`. I don't think `Button` provides/raises `MouseDown` unless may be with a custom template.

### Example:

```
<Button Grid.Row="3"
        Margin="5"
        Name="cmd_Clear"
        ClickMode="Press"
        Click="Cmd_Clear_MouseDown">Clear</Button>
```